# MVC 4 Custom Route Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have a multi-tenant MVC 4.5 site in which each tenant would like to map some custom routes of their own to one of our controllers.  Therefore the mapping needs to take place during Session Start and last for that session alone, not application wide.

for example if the host url is 
  sales.abc.com then sales.abc.com/products would redirect to salescontroller/index
  tickets.blahblah.net then /special/hotrocks would also redirect to salescontroller/index

when the tenant's session ends the route fails with 403

My thought would be to hook into the routing engine to inspect an incoming request, if it is one of the custom routes defined for that session then pass it along to the route handler for our controller/action.

Is this the right approach?  How do I implement multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a complex and clunky solution to a simple problem.

The MVC Routing system already provides a constraints system that allows you to define custom constraints.  You can also hook into your own Route object that can do custom routing.

Since you don't mention how you're doing your multi-tenancy, it's not easy to suggest a way to handle this, but I would start at custom routing which only enables the routes when a specific url is used (assuming your multi-tenancy is url based).

Comment: The multi-tenancy is through host headers (url based). I will look into constraints. Thank you.

Comment: @StuTheDog - That doesn't explain how you're doing multi-tenancy in MVC.  What technical solution are you using.  There are many ways to do it.